# Toast notifications duplicating in NextJS14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hot-toast

I'm using the latest NextJS and having issues rendering a toast notification from `react-hot-toast`.

The initial issue is that they cannot be rendered in server components, so I created a client component just for displaying this notification. It now displays it but twice, I have a feeling this could be strict mode, but I have no idea if it is and even so, why its duplicating.

The component should produce a toast notification if the `?authenticated=true` parameter is present in the URL.

The server component:

```
export default function Profile() {
    const { user, loggedIn } = useAuth()

    // For reference: 
    // const user = { id: 1234, email: 'example@gmail.com'}
    // const loggedIn = true


    if(!loggedIn) {
        return redirect('/')
    }

    if(loggedIn) {
        return (
            <section className="text-center">
                <SuccessfulSigninNotification />
                <h1>Profile page</h1>
                <h2>{user?.email}</h2>
            </section>
        )
    }

}
```

The client component:

```
"use client"

imports...

const SuccessfulSigninNotification = () => {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    const authenticated = searchParams.get('authenticated')


    useEffect(() => {
        if (authenticated === 'true') {
            toast.success('Successfully Signed In!')
        }
    }, [authenticated])

    return <></>

}

export default SuccessfulSigninNotification
```

I have also attempted to collect the param from the server component via `{searchParams}` but still experience the same duplication error.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning Next JS and also encountered similar issue today.
Have you tried disabling strict mode?

By adding following config to `next.config.mjs`

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}
```

Also, from the docs, there is following suggestion:

> To prevent duplicates of the same kind, you can provide a unique
> permanent id.
>
> ```
> toast.success('Copied to clipboard!', {
>   id: 'clipboard',
> });
> ```

Link [HERE](https://react-hot-toast.com/docs/toast#:%7E:text=Prevent%20duplicate%20toasts)

Comment: Disabling strict mode would fix the issue technically, but it shouldn’t be occurring with strict mode really